# Why are these Rails validations different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activemodel

```
  validates :password, :presence => { :on => :create },
            :length => { :within => 4..40 }
```

and

```
  validates :password, :presence => { :on => :create },
            :length => { :within => 4..40, :on => :save }
```

I thought the default for a validation was `:on => :save` which means on both :create and :update? But when I replace the first with the second specs start failing `expected valid? to return false, got true`.

What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, `:on => :save` is the default and means `on both update and create`, so it's not needed.  Perhaps you found a bug, but if i read your question, since we can't see your specs, your specs are passing without the :on => :save.  Leave it out and carry on.